# How to draw a arbitrary path with touch move on a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios

I know that you can draw a line easy by Core Graphic on UIView in a drawrect function. However, I only can draw a straight line。 If I want to draw a arbitrary path with the touch move, what should I do? Can someone give a hint?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `CGPoints` that are being passed to `touchesMoved:` and draw a line in between each on of those `CGPoints` in order to draw your arbitrary path. You would only need to draw a new line once, unless you are redrawing your screen, which means you would have to store all the points in an `NSMutableArray`, and redraw them every time. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669490/how-to-draw-line-on-touch-event