# Draw horizontal or vertical line using touch in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, paint

I am working on a project where I want that if user touch move in horizontal direction then horizontal line should draw and of user touch move in vertical direction then vertical line should draw. Kindly suggest some solution using Swift.
I tried below. But this is drawing free line.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
        let lastPoint = touch!.previousLocation(in: holderView)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: lastPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y))

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
        let currentPoint = touch!.location(in: holderView)

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: currentPoint.x, y: currentPoint.y))

        //Design path in layer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.orange.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20.0

        holderView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
         path=UIBezierPath()
    }
```

Comment: you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669490/how-to-draw-line-on-touch-event

Comment: what if user touches the screen and creates a curve path of points?

Comment: So many unknowns! Your code says, "there is a bezier path, when touch begins, jump to the touch position, when touch moves, draw line to the new position and display the result in a new sublayer, when touch ends, create a new bezier path". The sublayer logic seems to be extremely inefficient (creating hundreds of partially repeating sublayers) and bezier path creation  appears to be unnecessarily backwards but that is besides the point. Given the explanation of the logic above, could you clarify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SamipShah even if user tries to draw curve he would not be able to do that. The line would be always straight and vertical or horizontal direction.

Comment: @baglan the above code just draw path on touch. I tested this and its working.

Comment: @SanchitPaurush indeed, my understanding is, this is not what you wanted it to do. If that is so, could you describe what you want it to do? Say, instead of drawing a number of lines, on each touch and release you want it to draw just one line either vertically or horizontally depending on the dominant direction of the move. Thing, is, the answer depends on the outcome you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this.

```
class DrawingView: UIView {
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    var initialLocation = CGPoint.zero
    var finalLocation = CGPoint.zero
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupView(){
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
        self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self){
            initialLocation = location
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self){
            let dx =  location.x - initialLocation.x
            let dy = location.y - initialLocation.y

            finalLocation = abs(dx) > abs(dy) ? CGPoint(x: location.x, y: initialLocation.y) : CGPoint(x: initialLocation.x, y: location.y)

            path.removeAllPoints()
            path.move(to: initialLocation)
            path.addLine(to: finalLocation)

            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        }
    }
}
```